# How to play the video from local system using "SimpleMediaFensterPlayerController"

Tags: android, textureview

I am capturing video from video camera, and I want to view it before uploading. and I'm using SimpleMediaFensterPlayerController. its not playing the video.
is it possible to play the video captured and stored in local system . if so then how can it be done.

```html
 <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/videoTextureLayout"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomBtnContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        >
        <com.malmstein.fenster.view.FensterVideoView
            android:id="@+id/play_video_texture"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:keepScreenOn="true"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

        <com.malmstein.fenster.controller.SimpleMediaFensterPlayerController
            android:id="@+id/play_video_controller"
            android:layout_below="@+id/play_video_texture"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

The above is my xml to display video captured from local system.

Comment: `its not playing the video` any error messages?

Comment: NO,  it is logging as start playing: "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/20170704_120710-958078617.mp4". But video is not shown.

Comment: show how you play a video then

Comment: File mVideoFile = ImageUtils.createFileVideo();
            if (mVideoFile != null ) {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(mVideoFile.getPath());
                fos.write(byteArray);

                fos.close();
                if(mVideoFile.length()!= 0) {
                    textureView.setVideo((mVideoFile.getPath()));
                }
This code is working for video downloaded from server. but same is not working for local system video.

Comment: ok, VideoView is not able to play all the video formats. This means that your camera may take video in format, which can't be played by VideoView. Check in which format does the camera take video, and encoded with which codec